# How to pass two parameters to node.js file via querystring?

Tags: node.js, query-string

Consider the below code:

```
// upload.js
var fs = require('fs')
var newPath = "E:\\newPath";
var oldPath = "D:\\oldPath";

exports.uploadFile = function (req, res) {
fs.readFile(oldPath, function(err, data) {
    fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function(err) {
        fs.unlink(oldPath, function(){
            if(err) throw err;
            res.send("File uploaded to: " + newPath);
        });
    });
});
};

// app.js
var express = require('express'), // fetch express js library
upload = require('./upload'); // fetch upload.js you have just written

var app = express();
app.get('/upload', upload.uploadFile); 

app.listen(3000);
```

In the above code, I need to assign the new path dynamically by passing two parameters as query string such as

```
1. Drive and 2. Folder name.
```

How to give the query string in code file and how to run the program to achieve the GET request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access query-string parameters via `req.query`. Also, you could probably just use [fs.rename](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback) instead of manually reading, writing, and unlinking a file.

Comment: Could you please come up with a simple example?

Comment: `req.query.drive` and `req.query.folder`? For `fs.rename` it's just something like `fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function(err) { if (err) throw err; res.send('Rename successful'); });`

Comment: Also, you generally shouldn't use a GET request that changes things on the server. That should be reserved for other HTTP verbs, like POST. So you would use `app.post('/upload', upload.uploadFile);` and the client would POST to `/upload?drive=E&folder=newPath`. Then just assemble those two parameters to make a valid path.